# HP Envy 6 ultrabook touchpad wont use the gestures

Tags: touchpad

I quit Windows 8 for Ubuntu on my HP Envy 6 Ultrabook, but the touchpad won't work properly (I can't zoom in/out). In the settings there are no functions for zoom. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the touchpad drivers? Try to install the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package by running `sudo apt-get install -f xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` on the terminal.